# PDO won't return results from a SQLite database, or any exceptions

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

So I have a bit of code that I just *cannot* figure out. I have error reporting turned on, and I have the appropriate try/catch blocks, but the code below is *not* functioning. When I run this code, all I get is `bool(false)` from the `var_dump($result)`.

```
try
{
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:norming_database.db');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

/*... some other stuff in between ...*/

try
{
    $query = "SELECT stimulusName
            FROM responses
            WHERE workerId LIKE :workerId";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':workerId', $_GET['testWorkerId']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetch();
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "PDO Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

echo "<pre>" . var_dump($result) . "</pre>";
```

I'm getting no exceptions or errors. On top of that, if I run the query itself in my database manager (Valentia Studio), it returns exactly the result I'm expecting.

I suspect that there's some typo or something in my code that I'm failing to see after reading over it repeatedly. Is there anything blatantly wrong with how this is written?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yup, that's what I have! Still no errors or results! This is one of the more frustrating coding problems I've had in quite awhile and I've already sunk 6 hours into the issue...

Comment: Post your exact error description.

Comment: I'm literally getting no errors. I run this exact code and the only thing that prints out is `bool(false)`. Other than that, *no* errors have been produced; the code is just not functioning.

Comment: I suspect it's the query. Technically it reads `SELECT stimulusName FROM responses WHERE workerId LIKE 'your_get_var_here_if_it_exists'` - now, I don't know much about SQLite, but what is the actual query you have been using in your Valentia Studio? That `LIKE` query isn't using any wildcards, unless you  sent something bad via GET?

Comment: To test the query in Valentia, I copied it from PHP, pasted it into the query editor, did `echo $_GET['testWorkerId']`, copied what was printed, and pasted it into where `:workedId` was, surrounding it by quotes. So it's the exact same query in both places.

Comment: Try using `$db->errorInfo()` and `$db->errorCode()` methods to check if there's indeed something going on out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 0):

`$query = "SELECT stimulusName
           FROM responses
           WHERE workerId LIKE '%" . :workerId . "%'");`